# Start Microsoft Edge in silent printing (kiosk printing) mode from command prompt

Tags: printing, microsoft-edge

I'm developing a web app for a kiosk. I want to print the bill without print preview or any interaction with user. In chrome we ca do this by passing `--kiosk-printing` argument from command prompt.
Is there a similar method available for Microsoft Edge? The reason I'm switching from Chrome to Edge is Chrome always show the print preview for a short time (less than one sec in my case) even in the kiosk printing mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just fixed it, we can use `--kiosk-printing` argument as same as we use on chrome to enable silent printing on edge, but it doesn't solve the flash of print screen since both browsers are based on chromium.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --kiosk www.contoso.com --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen --no-first-run  --kiosk-printing
```

UPDATE 2024 Feb:

> in edge 112, unlike chrome, just saying `--kiosk-printing` not works
> and you should enable the whole kiosk mode by adding `--kiosk` and
> `--edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen`

HamedH

Comment: The print dialog flashing up is very annoying! - did you ever find a solution to that?

Comment: @mutex Sadly, no, I had to implement a whole new windows program and integrate it with the current web app to print the bills.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that is disappointing. Seems silly to have the kiosk-printing option when it looks so hacky.

Comment: in chrome you can just say  --kiosk-printing to use silent printing without kiosk mode, buy its seems than edge does not support silent printing without enabling the whole kiosk mode

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use --kiosk-printing argument in the same way we use it on chrome.

```
msedge.exe  --kiosk-printing
```

Comment: in edge 112, unlike chrome, just saying --kiosk-printing not works and you should enable the whole kiosk mode by adding '--kiosk' and '--edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen'