# Windows 10 Pro Kiosk With Edge - How To Skip Print Dialog

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I am using Edge on windows 10 pro kiosk.
I need configure Edge to skip print preview dialog.

How can I do this?

See:

https://snipboard.io/EhK4GJ.jpg

https://snipboard.io/LFou40.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start Microsoft Edge in silent printing (kiosk printing) mode from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65931706/start-microsoft-edge-in-silent-printing-kiosk-printing-mode-from-command-promp)

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the print preview dialog in Edge in kiosk mode using the flags like below:

```
--kiosk --kiosk-printing
```

You can add the flags after the Edge shortcut target like this:

[image]